# Webapp that runs process won't complete

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, shell

So I've got a couple of shell scripts that run on a server. They do some time intensive data gathering and then complete. They seem to work fine when I run them from the server. I'm now trying to automate these with a Spring webapp. Everything is running and I can run the scripts through ProcessBuilder, but for some reason, when the scripts are run through ProcessBuilder they only get about halfway and then just stop responding.

I'm really hoping someone will have some thoughts on why this might be. Unfortunately due to the work I can't really post much in the way of code. I can post the webapp code that runs the processes, which I'll do down below, but I can't post the scripts. If anyone has some thoughts please chime in. Thanks.

```
@Entity
public class Job implements Runnable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    //getters and setters

    @Override
    public void run() {
         Process p = null;

        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/opt/condor/bin/datafile"));
            bw.write(this.getName());
            bw.close();

            p = new ProcessBuilder("/opt/condor/bin/scripts/create-filter.sh").start();
            jobHelper(p);

            List<String> dates = datesBetween();
            status = "Running Master";

            for(String temp : dates) {
                String[] splitDate = temp.split("-");
                String tmpYear = splitDate[0];
                String tmpMonth = splitDate[1];
                String tmpDay = splitDate[2];

                log.info("Running Master script: master.sh " + this.getCustomer() + ", " + this.getProject() + ", " + tmpYear + ", " + tmpMonth + ", " + tmpDay);

                p = new ProcessBuilder("/opt/condor/bin/scripts/master.sh", this.getCustomer(), this.getProject(), tmpYear, tmpMonth, tmpDay).start();
                log.info("Entering job helper");
                jobHelper(p);
                log.info("exited job helper");
            }

        status = "Finished Master";
        log.info("Finished Master");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        log.error("IO Error: " , ioe);
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    log.info("Done running script");

    endTime = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());

    status = "Ended";

    JobManager.FinishJob(this);
    }

private boolean jobHelper(Process p) {
                log.info("inside job helper");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;

    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            log.info(line);

            if(line.contains("Uh oh!"))
                return true;
        }

    boolean running = true;
    while(running) {
                          log.info("waiting...");
        p.waitFor();
                          log.info("done waiting");
        running = false;
    }       

    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("IO Error: " , e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.error("Interrupted Exception: ", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        p.destroy();
    }

    return false;
}

}
```

I apologize for any syntactical errors you see, the code does compile and run so please just ignore them. I was copying and pasting the relevant bits of code and may have messed up something in that regard.

**EDIT**

I added some log statements in different places and can see that the code is entering my helper, which is why it is displaying output, but at some point it just stops. it doesn't ever seem to hit the log statements surrounding the p.waitFor() method. Clearly I'm not doing something right, which is understandable since threads are a huge weakpoint of mine. I'm guessing maybe it is getting hung up displaying stuff and I'm then getting a deadlock situation but I really don't understand where or how to fix it. Can anyone let me know what I'm screwing up and what I need to do to fix it? I could really use an example as well, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried outputting the stderror stream and seeing what it says?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to drain the output stream.

Comment: I'm not sure how to output the stderror stream. Also telling me I didn't drain the output stream doesn't help me much. If you could please offer some fixes I would appreciate it. Threading is a huge weakpoint of mine and even if I am told the problem I'm still not sure how to fix it without some examples. Thanks.

Comment: An `Entity` implementing `Runnable`... not a good idea

Comment: Well instead of criticizing my code which I'll be the first to admit is not the best, perhaps you could offer suggestions or examples?

Comment: @cardician: I've never seen this approach before... Just a guess, you may run into strange problems reg transaction mgmt, e.g. when will your transaction finish? Maybe there is some kind of deadlock? The trx may spawn across multiple threads, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after more research it seems that the problem was related to me not properly getting all the data from the input and error streams. I guess you're supposed to have multiple threads for each stream, which I still don't understand. I added a line that called the `redirectErrorStream()` method on the processbuilder object and that seems to have helped. I'm still not sure it won't hang again when processing greater amounts of data as I've seen a bunch of talk about all the streams needing to be in their own threads as I mentioned, but I'm not really sure how I'm supposed to do that. It's very hard to find a good concise example of how to use ProcessBuilder. However, this seems to have fixed the problem I was having.

Comment: this is the canonical article for using java processes correctly: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Comment: @cardician: It's not about critizing you, it's just about the unusual use of an Entity and its possible side-effects!

Answer (score 0):

I can not help much without more context on why your process is hanging.  However, your entity should not be runable.  Extract this to a service, you can store your process id in you entity if you need to map it back to a process.

Comment: I don't know why it's hanging. That's exactly what I'm trying to ask. And as I've said I'm really not good with threads or anything related so I'm just putting this code together as I go in whatever way I can make it work. I appreciate you providing a little more info on an alternative to having my Entity be runable. I can try altering that once I get the code to actually work.

Comment: @cardician: Give it a try without any context - remove all Spring + JPA dependencies and call the external process from within a separate program (JUnit etc.)